# The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUpgradeSiteCollectionJobDefinition threw an exception in Event Viewer

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am verifying the Event Viewer logs in my SharePoint server and found that there is an error with Event ID 6389.

Message: The Execute method of job definition Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUpgradeSiteCollectionJobDefinition (ID abd5b488-f6c1-4169-aa16-b26ee829b206) threw an exception.
Collection was modified, enumeration operation may not execute.

What does this error means? What could be the reason and solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The error itself generally means that we grabbed a collection of objects (sites) and one or more items in that collection (a site) has been modified in some way. This invalidates the collection of objects this particular job has.

So with that said, are you upgrading sites from v14.5 to v15 in SharePoint 2013? This is the only time you'd need to be concerned with this particular job. In addition, if this is a one-time error, which does happen, you may ignore it as long as the job has run successfully in the past or after the error. You can check the job status in Central Administration -> Monitoring -> Timer Job Status and then look at the history.